# I cannot set up Google Play Games Services

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm struggling with Google Play Services and I don't know how to get them work.
I published an application on Google Play Store. I realized the app with Unity.
The problem is, that once I upload the .apk on the Google Developer Console and I publish it, the GPS doesn't work as expected: leaderboards doesn't show up and sign-in doesn't work. I'm using this Unity plugin to import GPS to the project (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).
That said, this is how I configured the Google Play Console project:

- I created a linked app to the project. I entered the SHA-1 contained in the Upload Certificate that Google gave me.
- I built the app, signin it with the Google Upload Certificate

At first I was signin the app with my local SHA-1 and not with the one included in the Upload Certificate. So I downloaded the certificate, "merged" it with my keystore and then built the app with the updated keystore. But nothing changed.
I really don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance,
Roberto.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you published your app. Note that game settings should also be published.

If you haven't done yet, follow these [recommendations when setting up your game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#avoiding_common_setup_problems) to use the Google Play games services.

1. **Set up your game with the Google Play Console**

   If you created an Oauth 2.0 client ID for your app in the Google Play Console, Google Play games services will not know about the association between the game’s achievement and leaderboards and the client ID. To create this association, you should first link your app with the game as described in [Create a linked application](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application).
2. **Use the correct application ID in Android**

   The application ID is a required string resource that you must reference in your Android manifest.
3. **Sign your APK with the correct certificate**

   When linking your Android app to your game in the Google Play Console, you must use exactly the same package name and certificate fingerprint that you used to publish your app. If there is a mismatch, calls to Google Play games services will fail. You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint, and use the same package name for both.
4. **When developing for Android, include the Play Games SDK as a library project, not as a standalone JAR**

   Make sure that the Google Play services SDK is referenced as a library project in your Android project, otherwise this could lead to errors when your app is unable to find Google Play services resources.
5. **Sign in with a tester account during development**

   You should always enable your Google Play Console publisher account for testing.
6. **At release, publish the Play Games services settings first before you publish your game**

   When releasing your game, remember to first publish your game settings by using the Publish Game option in the Google Play Console.

See [Setting Up Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=nkJS_W-VC9I) to learn more.